# Adjust Div height and width depending the content of said div

Tags: html, css

I am looking for a pure CSS way of having a container div automatically adjust it's width and height based on what content is inside it, for the purposes of centring the aforementioned content within another div.

I have tried setting the height and width to auto, but that doesn't help.

Any help you can offer would be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

The CSS:

```
.imageThumbnails {

    position: relative;
    margin: auto;
    height: auto;
    width: auto;
}

.imageThumbnailOne {

    position: relative;
    float: left;
    height: 78px;
    width: 91px;
    background-image: url("thumbnail1.png");

}

.imageThumbnailTwo {

    position: relative;
    float: left;
    height: 80px;
    width: 76px;
    background-image: url("thumbnail2.png");
    margin-left: 29px;
}

.imageThumbnailThree {

    position: relative;
    float: left;
    height: 76px;
    width: 89px;
    background-image: url("thumbnail3.png");
    margin-left: 29px;
}
```

The HTML:

```
<div class="imageThumbnailsContainer">

    <div class="imageThumbnails">
        <div class="thumbnailOne"><a></a></div>
        <div class="thumbnailTwo"><a></a></div>
        <div class="thumbnailThree"><a></a></div>
    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: `imageThumbnails {` change to `.imageThumbnails {`

Comment: or completely remove that block since it does nothing anyways.

Comment: Oops, that was a typo in my question. It has a dot in the actual CSS file. Thanks for pointing it out. :)

Comment: The purpose of .imageThumbnails is to collect the three thumbnails together and centre them as if they were one element.

Answer (score 1):

You need to clear the `.imageThumbnails` div. You can do that with `.imageThumbnails { overflow: hidden; }` You can also remove the `position: relative` from everything.